Internal gear hub - missing parts
I've recently bought a wheel with Shimano Nexus SG-C3001-7R hub.
There are some parts missing on it, including sprocket:

I already have the compatible shifter (SL-7S50), but it ends with just bare cable, so no way of attaching it to the hub without additional hardware.
What do I need to install this wheel on a bike?
